# Outlook attachments data dump within date range

Tags: vba, outlook

I built a script that downloads all the attachments in a particular outlook inbox, but I need to modify it so it will only grab emails that fall within a particular date range.

Here's my code for downloading all the attachments in the folder:

```
Sub DlAttachments()
    MsgBox ("Cross fingers and click button to start download.")
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    strFolderName = "Special Inbox Admin"
    Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders(strFolderName)
    Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox")

    Set colItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each objMessage In colItems
        intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
        If intCount > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To intCount
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\SP_INBOX_DUMP_temp\" & objFolder & "_" & _
                    objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
            Next
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox ("Download complete. Files downloaded to C:\SP_INBOX_DUMP_temp\")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SentOn` property of the object message. That would change your code to :

```
Dim myDate as Date

For Each objMessage In colItems
    intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
    'get the sent date
    sentDate = objMessage.SentOn
    'ref date (adapt format to your system date format dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy)
    myDate = dateValue("31/1/2009")   
    If myDate > sentDate Then
        'do whatever --> Exit For ?
    End If
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\SP_INBOX_DUMP_temp\" & objFolder & "_" & _
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Regards,

Max

Comment: This is exactly the property I needed. should myDate look something like: Format(06/29/2011,"mm/dd/yyyy") ?

Comment: @David: you only have to compare with kind of string >> "11/10/2011" > sentDate worked for me

Comment: Tried that, it's giving me "12/28/2009" > "12/22/2010". I think it's comparing the strings qua strings, so the comparison operator gives you where they would fall in alphabetical sorting, not date sorting. The Format() function didn't help either. Is there anything like to_date()?

Comment: i missed it sorry. it seems like we should use `dateValue("3/1/2009")`, i will edit my post to use this function

Comment: Not gonna lie: I haven't had a chance to test this (and I've already moved beyond the project), but your solution looks about right. Accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Restrict method to limit the items in your collection to just those within a certain date range:

```
Set colItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '06/01/2011 12:00' And [ReceivedTime] < '06/02/2011 12:00'")
```

Essentially what this does is limit the emails in the resulting collection to those received on 6/1. This is air code so you might need to play with the syntax.

More about the Restrict Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220369(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer so much as a workaround: having been unable to successfully implement Max's solution, I copied the emails in the date range to a separate folder and modified my code to act on the new folder. Kinda dirty but hey, it works.

Comment: i edited my answer (sorry for the delay) with a new solution - tried it on simple test cases in my Outlook